# get two div to be on the same margin line and stay there even if the browser's size is changed

Tags: html, css

I have two divs. One is around a h4 and the other around a p. I want the p to be in the middle so its set as margin-left: auto; and margin-right:auto; I dont want the h4 to also be in the middle I want it to be set so its inline with the left side of the div.

```
---------------page size-----------------

           ---<h4>---
           --------<p>-------
           ---In the center--
           ----of the page---
           ------------------

-----------------------------------------
```

Here is a little example of what I want it to be like. If I manually set the margin-left to fit in with the position then if someone has a different screen size then it won't be there. This is for a school project so I am not very good at html or css so forgive me if its really simple or stupid.

Comment: Can you maybe provide some sample code of what you have so far. Maybe a jsFiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Margin: auto for Right and Left will not work because it gets all width. Margin: auto works when you has set fixed width for and element. In this case, you can give "Text-align: center" to

and it make it simple.

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
div.h4-wrapper{
  margin: 0 0;
}
p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="h4-wrapper">
  <h4>On Left Side</h4>
</div>

<div>
  <p>On middle.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont quite understand what u mean?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply though

Comment: Hey, I played around with what you send and I got them both inline with eachother which is really cool. But now its not in the center of the page. If I change the Width: 300px; value then it moves but I want it exactly in the middle.

Comment: You have two divs. And In the div which wrap <h4> you want this <h4> to be aligned to Left. But, the div with <p>, you want the <p> to be in the center of the div. "margin: 0 auto;" Works when you have <p> 100px width, so browser can calculate margins cause he knows <p> has 100px of width. In this case, if you don't set a width to <p> you can give "text-align:center" so text inside <p> will be displayed in the middle

Comment: You want <p> to be in the middle or the <div> which contains the <p> to be in the middle?